# Sites tagged to a patent

Tags: patent-applications, patent-services, websites

Is there a way to tag a patent to a specific site or check the sites that are tagged to a particular patent?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? It’s not at all clear. Are you asking for programming advice?

Comment: No. I am asking if it is a common cause for some sites to be tagged to a particular patent? For example, sites that are related to what the patent is about.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what "common cause" means in this context. Nor am I sure what you mean by "tag". Is that linking to or referring to?